# Loading a yaml file in Electron app

Tags: javascript, yaml, electron, fs

I am trying to load a big set of data stored in a .yml file into my Electron app:

```
import yaml from 'js-yaml';
import fs from 'fs';

let data = {};

try {
  data = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('src/app/data/items.en.yml', 'utf8'));
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error)
}

module.exports = data;
```

This works in development, however, when I package the app the .yml file cannot be loaded. What would be the "correct" way to load such data into my app?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exception do you get in production?

Comment: and mayby give a link to yaml file